# Building dss library lastest version

Tags: maven

Dear members of support,
I am trying to build the [dss](https://github.com/esig/dss) code from master branch. But I get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dss-asic-xades: Could not resolve dependencies for project eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-asic-xades:jar:5.8.RC1: Failure to find eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-asic-common:jar:tests:5.8.RC1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

but dependency exists. See [here](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/artifact/#browse/search=keyword%3Ddss-asic-common%2C%205.8:912d0fe7b81923922722cd3a6a664b4f:dfbef09efe1644eafaf483206c4d0b83)

Could you help me, please?

Comment: So either this dependency does not exist or you have network/firewall issues.

Comment: @JFabianMeier but dependecy exists https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/artifact/#browse/search=keyword%3Ddss-asic-common%2C%205.8:912d0fe7b81923922722cd3a6a664b4f:dfbef09efe1644eafaf483206c4d0b83. And aacording pom.xml repo is correctly set

Comment: If you are in a company network, then the download is probably blocked by the network.